# Insert element before and after heading except for first heading

Tags: jquery, insert, element, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a list of h5's:

```
<div id="accordion"><h5>One</h5>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<h5>Two</h5>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<h5>Three</h5>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<h5>Four</h5>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<h5>Five</h5>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p></div>
```

And I want to turn them into accordions using jQuery UI accordion which takes the first element as the contain so I want to wrap the content between each of the h5's. if I use .after() and .before() it picks up both the closing and opening tags of the `</h5>` and I also don't know how to get the first element to not insert a closing tag above it:

What I have so far which obviously isn't working:

```
var insert = true;
$("#accordion h5").each(function(event) {
    // All of them have a div immediatly after it.
    $(this).after("<div>");
    if (insert === true) {
        insert = false;
    } else {
        $(this).before("</div>");
    }
});
```

to clarify, my output i want to look like this, but there will not always be p tags as the content it can be anything.

```
<div id="accordion">
<h5>One</h5>
<div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p></div>
<h5>Two</h5>
<div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
<h5>Three</h5>
<div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p></div>
...
</div>
```

Comment: How do you want the markup to look once the code has run? Do you just want each `h5` element to end up in a `div`?

Comment: Actually I want it to go like <h5>One</h5><div> ... content <p></p><span></span> whatever ... </div> then the next one starts <h5>Two</h5><div> .....content ..... </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this is what you want:

```
$('#accordion > h5').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('h5').wrapAll('<div/>');
});
```

Which would wrap all of the content between each `h5` in a `div`

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n7d9e/)

**edit**

To insert a `div` when there is no content just add a simple condition such as:

```
$this = $(this); 
if ($this.next('h5').length) {
  $this.after('<div/>');
} else {
  $this.nextUntil('h5').wrapAll('<div/>');
}
```

This is basically saying if the next element is a `h5` (ie. there is no content), insert an empty `div`, otherwise wrap all of the contents until the next `h5` in a `div`.

Comment: This is fairly close! nice one ... although sometimes there is no content between the <h5>One</h5>  <h5>Two</h5> and it would need to insert a <div></div>

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to nextUntil() - amazing function!

Answer (score 0):

You need the wrap function:

```
$("#accordion h5").wrap('<div />');
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score 0):

Use this selector so get a hold of all h5's but the first one:

```
$('#accordion h5:not(:first)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .not() selector in your each function, then  inside of .not(), use the :eq(0) selector, 0 is the index of the first element. In your case:

```
$("#accordion h5").not(':eq(0)').each(function(event) {
    //your code
});
```

hope it helps

Comment: using .not(':eq(0)') will skip the first element from iteration